# iOS virtual keyboard size without notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, virtual-keyboard

I need to scroll up my scrollView, when textFiewl is tapped that is bellow the virtual keyboard.  I call `[self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];`. To get the screen's visible area, i obviously need the KB size.

I am familiar with

```
NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

CGSize kbSize = [self.view convertRect:
                 [info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue]
                              fromView:nil].size;
```

however, it doesn't work for me, because when a user taps on possibly half-hidden textfield, i don't receive the keyboard notification.

So i call the method in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, which is called before keyboard will send message, and so i don't know the KB size on first tap.

So the question is: is possible to get the KB size, without invoking corresponding notification?
Programmaticaly, not hardcoding.

Comment: Just store the keyboard frame when you first get the notification?

Comment: thats what im trying to do - store it in property. But can i somehow invoke the notification myself?

Comment: No. But the keyboard will never appear without sending the notification, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Even if you're moving from one textField to another, you should have had the notification from when the first field started editing.

Comment: If the "half-hidden" field is the first one the user taps on, then there is something wrong with your observing code, and you should edit the question to include that. What object observes the notification? When does it register?

Comment: @user1244109, good question, I am hitting it right now. Have you ever found any solutions to this problem? You are so damn right about this: "textFieldDidBeginEditing:, which is called before keyboard will send message, and so i don't know the KB size on first tap"

Answer (score 3):

**You are doing it wrong.**

You need to also listen for the keyboard show/hide notifications and then adjust your screen.

Here is a sample skeleton code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardChangedStatus:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardChangedStatus:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Get Keyboard size

- (void)keyboardChangedStatus:(NSNotification*)notification {
    //get the size!
    CGRect keyboardRect;
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardRect];
    keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.size.height;
    //move your view to the top, to display the textfield..
    [self moveView:notification keyboardHeight:keyboardHeight];
}

#pragma mark View Moving

- (void)moveView:(NSNotification *) notification keyboardHeight:(int)height{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

    if ([[notification name] isEqual:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification]) {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y = 0;
        hasScrolledToTop = YES;
    } 
    else {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard (you need to adjust the value here)
        rect.origin.y = -height;
    }

    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: i know all of this, and have it implemented. Sure i listen to notifications. The problem is, that they are not sent if the KB is up already, and user tapped on half-hidden textfield - i need it to become fully visible.

Besides, the question was "how to get KB size without notification". In my opinion, the answer should be voted down

Comment: How can the keyboard be up, if you subscribe to the notification in the viewWillAppear function of the viewController? And AFAIK this is the only way to get they keyboard size. If you don't like the answer don't accept it, but downvoting a completely working code sample because you don't like the solution, is the wrong way to start here. I'm sorry I spent my time, trying to help you. Won't happen again.

Comment: 1.The KB might be up, if user tapped other textfield, and then tapped on half-hidden. 2.I didn't say that i don't like the solution, i said that this is not the solution. 3.I mentioned downvoting because such answer may lead people to think that this is another "how to scroll when KB appeared" question. 4.I dont know why you take it like that - if someone said that your answer should be downvoted and argumented it. Its not like i have something against you personally, right? I guess everyone has different margins on whats worth downvoting..

Comment: ..i dont know if we shold continue this discussion, but the way i see it, _AFAIK this is the only way to get they keyboard size_ shoud have been the answer to this question. Dont take it badly. And i will appreciate your help in future, if you'll be willing to help. Cheers.

Comment: I have this same issue, and I think what he was trying to get across is that textFieldDidBeginEditing is called before the notification so on the first tap he does not know the keyboard size, which is what he said. Really wish someone had an answer for this.